# No token from TokenStorage on test environment

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I want to include the logged in user's id to my logger.
So I have added a `monolog.processor` that adds the user id to the 'extra'-portion of the record, and added a custom format string that displays the id.

On my dev environment this works (mostly) as expected, but on the test environment it does not work at all, the `TokenStorage` always returns `null` on `getToken()`.

There are no specific `security` configs for dev or test. The biggest differences between the configs is this part:

```
framework:
  test: ~
  session:
    storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
  profiler:
    collect: false
```

I have add this to my dev config but could not reproduce the symptoms. I can only reproduce by making symfony think it really is in test.

To be honest, I don't even know where to begin to debug this.

Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour?
Any ideas how I could debug this so I can get to an answer?

Answer (score -1):

In order to have a token you should be inside on of the symfony firewalls.

If any of the firewalls aren't matched by the URI, symfony security is not triggered and you will not have a token.

If it is a public area allow anonymous users from root '/*' and use ACL for the rest of the URI (or actions). Anonymous users will have the role IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
```

Documentation: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: Well yes, I understand that. And I also state in my question that 'On my dev environment this works (mostly) as expected'.

Comment: If you are certain that it is not an issue on the config files. Check the bundles you use on the development on AppKernel. I assume you clear the symfony cache for all environments and try to use the chrome private mode to test it with fresh cookies.